# Dll's get checked out automatically in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time I try to build my project I get pop up messages as in the image. I am using TFS 2010. I tried deleting the dll's,unchecking read-only option for the dll's.
But I still get this annoying pop-up for many of the dll's.The dll's are automatically checked out by the user who builds it first.How can I solve this problem?
Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the DLL that are generated by the Visual Studio Solution ?
If it's the case, it's a **very bad idea** to put them under source control, at least at the location where they are generated!

If you still want to store the DLL on the source control, create a "repository" folder somewhere and copy the generated files there, but don't put under source control every folder that are generated by Visual Studio (Bin, Obj, etc.)

Comment: My solution has websites which has dependency on 3rd party Dlls. is there any quick fix other than converting them to web applications ?

Comment: I don't understand this comment, can you explain more, please?

Comment: I have dependency on a third party DLLs.These DLLs are in the bin folder as my solution contains websites and not web applications

Comment: Ok, in this case the only way is to manually check-out the file. It would be a different story if you had WebApp, but as it's not the case, you don't have another solution.

Comment: Also Unchecking Tool/options/ Enviroment / Document - "
"Allow editing of read-only files,warn when attempt to save" option gets rid of the pop up messages